# Input type date not updated in Android browser

Tags: javascript, android, html, angularjs, datepicker

I am developing a web page that has an input with type date. I am using AngularJS to bind the data. The input element is simple as follows:

```
<input type="date" ng-model="myCtryl.startDate"/>
```

Whenever I click on the input, a native datepicker popup opens as expected. Then I select a date and the input field updates. This works in every browser in web and mobile platforms, except for Android's stock browser. In Android's stock browser, I select a date from the native datepicker, but the date in the input is never updated.

In the controller, I have my date defined normally:

```
this.startDate = new Date();
```

This is all the related code. I searched the web but couldn't find a solution, is there a known issue?

Comment: What is the testing device and Android version?

Comment: Samsung Galaxy S3 Android v4.3,
Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini Android v4.3,
Samsung Galaxy S4 Mini Android v4.2.2